# How can I optimize this SQL query with ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization, sql-order-by

I'm trying to optimize this query because the DB it runs against is huge and the host says this query is causing a serious load on the server. I've read some of the other answers about how to replace ORDER BY RAND() but I don't know enough about SQL to adapt those answers to this particular query. Can anyone help? TIA

```
  SELECT COUNT( p.prod_id ) AS no_prod, s.*
    FROM product p, seller s
   WHERE s.admin_status = '1' 
     AND s.pay_status = '1' 
     AND s.sub_type != '' 
     AND p.seller_id = s.seller_id 
GROUP BY s.seller_id 
  HAVING COUNT( p.prod_id )>5 
ORDER BY RAND() 
   LIMIT 0, 4
```

Comment: What other questions/answers have you read?? Links please?

Comment: I don't see how this query would even work - doesn't it complain that  fields in the SELECT are missing from the GROUP BY?

Comment: @Ben most of those involve 1 one random row (LIMIT 1) which is easier than retrieving 4 rows. The 3rd one involves multiple rows but did not get a solid answer.

Comment: @joshuahedlund, fair point, though most were also involving full scans of the table as this one would. I'll try and find a better example :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off adding a non-unique index which includes the fields **seller.admin_status, seller.pay_status, seller.sub_type**.  You'll get the biggest bang for your buck by indexing fields referenced in your WHERE clause.

Comment: I believe the problem is that ORDER BY RAND() does not use indexes and must scan the whole table. (http://ask.use-the-index-luke.com/questions/11/order-by-rand-can-use-index)

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

```
SET @MAX_SELLER_ID = SELECT MAX(seller_id) FROM seller;


SELECT COUNT( p.prod_id ) AS no_prod,
       s.*

FROM (
  -- preselect a big bunch of random sellers
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM seller
  WHERE seller.id IN (
    FLOOR( RAND() * @MAX_SELLER_ID )
   ,FLOOR( RAND() * @MAX_SELLER_ID )
   ,... -- repeat or generate list of random ids in your app
  )
) AS s
INNER JOIN product p

WHERE s.admin_status = '1' 
  AND s.pay_status = '1' 
  AND s.sub_type != '' 
  AND p.seller_id = s.seller_id 

GROUP BY s.seller_id 
HAVING COUNT( p.prod_id )>5 

ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0, 4;
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Just don't forget to check if all 5 required rows has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

Serious load is being caused by your SQL because of `ORDER BY RAND()`. You can google for reasons why this is a problem, and suggested fixes on how to accomplish the same effect in other ways.

The best explanation I could find after some googling came from a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45536) regarding this same issue on a solaris system:

> ORDER BY RAND() uses filesort and can not behave as fast as ORDER BY some_key.
>   This happens, because when you use ORDER BY RAND() is same if you write query like:
>   `SELECT id, rand() FROM t1 ORDER BY RAND();` This means rand() will be created for every row in the table.